# Hibernate getting a list of entities through a foreign key, without attribute

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, maven

I want to retrieve a list of Task entities from the task table, by a specific `corporate_id` which connects them. The problem I seem to encounter is that it cannot find the `corporate_id` column since Hibernate looks at the class which does not have a `corporate_id` attribute. Is there any way that this can be fixed?

I've already tried to make a `corporate_id` attribute, but that gives me a `NullPointerException`.

I have a `CorporateEvent` class:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name="corporate_event")
public class CorporateEvent extends Event {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "id_generator")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "id_generator", sequenceName = "corporate_event_id_seq", allocationSize = 1)
    @Column(name = "corporate_id", updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private int id;

    @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="corporateEvent")
    private List<Task> tasks;
```

and a `Task` Class:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name="task")
public class Task {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "id_generator")
  @SequenceGenerator(name="id_generator", sequenceName = "task_task_id_seq", allocationSize=1)
  @Column(name="task_id", updatable = false, nullable = false)
  private int id;

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name="corporate_id")
  private CorporateEvent corporateEvent;

  @Column(name="name")
  private String taskName;

  @Column(name="description")
  private String description;
```

Here is the Hibernate methods I have tried so far:

```java
public List<Task> getTasksByCorporateEvent(CorporateEvent corporateEvent){
       session = ConnectRepository.factory.getCurrentSession();
       session.beginTransaction();

       CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = session.getCriteriaBuilder();
       CriteriaQuery<Task> criteriaQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(Task.class);
       Root<Task> root = criteriaQuery.from(Task.class);

      criteriaQuery.select(root).where(criteriaBuilder.equal(root.get("corporateEvent.corporateID"), corporateEvent.getId()));
      Query<Task> query = session.createQuery(criteriaQuery);
      List result = query.getResultList();
```

and this:

```java
List<Task> result = session.createQuery("SELECT t FROM Task t WHERE t.corporate_id = :id").setParameter("id", corporateEvent.getId()).getResultList();
```

These are the database tables on the two classes:

`CorporateEvent` table:

```sql
create table corporate_event
(
    title            varchar,
    date             varchar(1000),
    location         varchar,
    description      varchar,
    max_participants integer,
    expenses         varchar(2000),
    corporate_id     serial not null
        constraint corporate_event_pk
            primary key,
    tasks            varchar(4000)
);

alter table corporate_event
    owner to si3_2019_group_5;

create unique index corporate_event_id_uindex
    on corporate_event (corporate_id);
```

`Task` table:

```sql
create table task
(
    task_id      serial not null constraint task_pk primary key,
    name         varchar,
    description  varchar(1000),
    corporate_id integer
        constraint corporate_id
            references corporate_event
            on update cascade on delete cascade
);

alter table task owner to si3_2019_group_5;

create unique index task_task_id_index on task (task_id);
```

**Update**
After adding the corrections made by Obi-Wan, I can no longer save my object. Here's the stacktrace:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Building Eventer 1.0-SNAPSHOT
------------------------------------------------------------------------

--- maven-resources-plugin:2.5:resources (default-resources) @ Eventer ---
[debug] execute contextualize
Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
Copying 11 resources

--- maven-compiler-plugin:3.6.1:compile (default-compile) @ Eventer ---
Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date

--- exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec (default-cli) @ Eventer ---
Nov 18, 2019 1:10:45 PM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.4.8.Final}
Nov 18, 2019 1:10:45 PM org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager <clinit>
INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.0.Final}
Nov 18, 2019 1:10:46 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
WARN: HHH10001002: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
Nov 18, 2019 1:10:46 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001005: using driver [org.postgresql.Driver] at URL [jdbc:postgresql://tek-mmmi-db0a.tek.c.sdu.dk:5432/si3_2019_group_5_db]
Nov 18, 2019 1:10:46 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001001: Connection properties: {user=si3_2019_group_5, password=****}
Nov 18, 2019 1:10:46 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001003: Autocommit mode: false
Nov 18, 2019 1:10:46 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl$PooledConnections <init>
INFO: HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 1 (min=1)
Nov 18, 2019 1:10:46 PM org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect <init>
INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
Nov 18, 2019 1:10:50 PM org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder bindClass
WARN: HHH000503: A class should not be annotated with both @Inheritance and @MappedSuperclass. @Inheritance will be ignored for: com.mycompany.domain.event.Event.
Nov 18, 2019 1:10:50 PM org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl addIdentifierGenerator
WARN: HHH000069: Duplicate generator name id_generator
Nov 18, 2019 1:10:50 PM org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl addIdentifierGenerator
WARN: HHH000069: Duplicate generator name id_generator
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.mycompany.repositories.EventRepository.saveCorporateEvent(EventRepository.java:57)
    at com.mycompany.domain.event.EventManager.createCorporateEvent(EventManager.java:30)
    at com.mycompany.eventer.Eventer.main(Eventer.java:64)
------------------------------------------------------------------------
BUILD FAILURE
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total time: 7.987s
Finished at: Mon Nov 18 13:10:50 CET 2019
Final Memory: 9M/100M
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec (default-cli) on project Eventer: Command execution failed. Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1) -> [Help 1]

To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.

For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

Here's the save `corporateEvent` to the database method:

```
public int saveCorporateEvent(CorporateEvent corporateEvent) {

        try {
            session = ConnectRepository.factory.getCurrentSession();
            session.beginTransaction();
            session.persist(corporateEvent);
            session.getTransaction().commit();
            return corporateEvent.getId();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        } finally {
            session.close();
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

I also added `@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="corporateEvent")` to the OneToMany annotation in the `CorporateEvent` class, since it was giving me a lot of other exceptions (duplicated ID's and "unsaved transient instance).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should update the `One to Many` relation inside the `CorporateEvent` to

```java
@OneToMany
@JoinColumn(name = "task_id")
private List<Task> tasks;
```

The `createQuery` should work if the query is changed to

`SELECT t FROM Task t WHERE t.corporateEvent.id = :id`

But this HQL would make a join between `Tasks` and `CorporateEvent`. 
In order to remove the join, you can create a new field inside the `Task` entity for loading only the `corporate_id` instead of fetching the entire `CorporateEvent` object.

```java
@Basic
@Column(name = "corporate_id")
private Integer corporateEventId
```

And afterwards, you can use this HQL

`SELECT t FROM Task t WHERE t.corporateEventId = :id`

Comment: With your solution, i get a nullPointerException when I'm trying to save the object. Im not sure if it is the database, that doesn't map correctly. I have only changed what was written in your answer, the rest is just as the original post.

Comment: Can you add the error stacktrace to the question description?

Comment: I have added a stacktrace and the save method as an update to the question now, I hope it makes sense.